# jQuery CSS Switching with Media Query Defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media

I have a website I'm trying to build with a mobile version, using CSS media queries in order to establish the two in the HTML:

```
<link id="fullcss" title="desktop version" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="only screen and (min-device-width:481px)" href='desktopstyle.css' />

<link id="mobicss" title="mobile version" rel='alternate stylesheet' type='text/css'  media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href='mobistyle.css' />
```

The mobile media query is only so large because I've shotgunned all hi-res phones along with the typical iPhone.

In my body I have two links:

```
<a id="css-full" href="#desktop">Desktop View</a>
<a id="css-mobi" href="#mobile">Mobile View</a>
```

Which I want to show/hide depending on the current sheet (it's in the CSS).

I'm trying to provide the option for users to switch to the desktop stylesheet on a mobile device and vice-versa, using jQuery or Javascript. Currently, it looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
/* CSS switch */
$("#css-full").click(function(){
    $("#fullcss").attr(href, "desktopstyle.css");
    $("#mobicss").attr(href, "desktopstyle.css");
});
$("#css-mobi").click(function(){
    $("#mobicss").attr(href, "mobistyle.css");
    $("#fullcss").attr(href, "mobistyle.css");
});
});
```

I'm not very familiar with jQuery so obviously this isn't working for me. What's the best way to tackle this problem? I cannot use PHP, though, sadly.

Thanks!

Comment: This: `.attr(href, "mobistyle.css")` I think should be `.attr('href', "mobistyle.css")`, or probably `.prop('href', "mobistyle.css")`. But I imagine you'd be better off using a detect script (maybe paired with a style to detect kept in a mobile `@media` query-accessible stylesheet, if media queries are more reliable on mobile devices) and toggle only one stylesheet link, not two.

Comment: Even fixing the attributes, the second (mobile) CSS sheet never seems to activate.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed that. Looking around, I think it's something about having persistent vs preferred vs alternate stylesheets. Removing the title from the desktop link seems to at least keep the appropriate stylesheet attached to each version.

Now it's a matter of trying to switch between the two, which is still something to work on.

Thank you for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the 'href' property in your code

```
$("#fullcss").attr('href', "desktopstyle.css");
$("#mobicss").attr('href', "desktopstyle.css");
```